# CONTEXT UNDEFINED Error while using React.Context with React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm new to React Navigation 5 and wish to learn how to use React.Context with this library.

I create a **context** before declaring  my **App** as follows. Please don't mind the values as these are just for testing.

```
const ContactsContext = React.createContext('light')
```

Now inside my **App**, I wrap my **NavigationContainer** inside **Context.Provider** as follows

```
<ContactsContext.Provider value="dark">
  <NavigationContainer>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  </NavigationContainer>
</ContactsContext.Provider>
```

Inside the **NavigationContainer** is a **TabNavigator**, whose first tab is a **StackNavigator** and its first stack is **ContactListScreen**. This is where I'm reading from the context as follows

```
static contextType = ContactsContext
```

Unfortunately, I get an error ***ContactsContext is not defined*** pointing to the above line.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for following along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't provided much detail. A few ideas:

1 Have you exported your 
export default UserContext

2 Does your import statement look like import { ContactsContext } from 'path to context.js'

3 Are you using a Class component, functional components don't use this form.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to provide more detail.

However, your idea #1 has worked. I forgot  to export/import ContactsContext. 

Thank you brother :)